# Как создаётся приоритет зависимый от разных полей?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Сайт на php. Цель создать некий **приоритет продвижения в списке**.

Рассмотреть будет удобнее на ПРИМЕРЕ товара у которого есть цена, рейтинг, дата создания.
Как грамотно создать продвижение в топ в зависимости от этих полей?

Пока в голову пришло только создать отдельный пункт "приоритет" и насиловать его каждый раз при изменении остальных параметров сложными формулами (цена рейт и т. д. скорей всего вообще будут в др таблицах) и отсортировать при выводе по нему.

**Есть какие-то более адекватные решения?** как вообще делается подобное в поисковых системах?

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку вы поставили метку "SEO" первый вариант предложу, как бы сделал SEO специалист, если нет данных о трафике по отдельным страницам товаров.

Вариант №1 (как бы сделал SEO специалист):
1) Нужно собрать для отдельных товаров класетеры ключевых слов, собрать частотности и позиции ваших страниц с товарами в поисках яндекса и гугла с помощью программы "KeyCollector" и на основе списка определить  приоритетность.

Вариант №2 (на основании данных о внутренней активности):
1) В этом случае приоритет будет распределён по спискам "Популярность" (кол-во посещений) -> "Кол-во голосов" (рейтинг) -> и т.д. если помог примите ответ!)